# useEffect and async()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

In the `useEffect()` hook, I am basically trying to add an `'id'` to each `'item'`object mapped to `tempData`, by incrementing the `lastIndex` state in each iteration. However, all the `item.id` s that have been mapped returned 0 (the initial state value).

I am guessing there is something wrong with invoking the `setLastIndext` function in the iterations? Thanks.

```
const SearchAppointments  = React.memo(() => {


  const [data, setData] = useState([ ])

  const [lastIndex, setLastIndex] = useState(0)

  useEffect( () => {
    const fetchData = async() => {
      var response = await fetch('../data.json');
      var result = await response.json()
      var tempData = result.map( item => {
        item.id = lastIndex;
        setLastIndex(lastIndex => lastIndex + 1);
        return item
      })
      setData(tempData)
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [])

    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
})
```

Comment: Why not do `result.map( (item,index) => ({...item,id:index})`? You can set lastIndex to results.length. The effect will only run once so not sure why you even need lastIndex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setLastIndex` is async function the value of `lastIndex` will only be updated in next render, but `result.map` is sync function ==> lastIndex always 0 in `result.map`

You can try this:

```js
const SearchAppointments  = React.memo(() => {


  const [data, setData] = useState([ ])
  // You not really need this lastIndex state for setting id for your data item, but somehow you want it after setData you can keep this and set to the last index of the item in fetched data
  const [lastIndex, setLastIndex] = useState(0)

  useEffect( () => {
    const fetchData = async() => {
      var response = await fetch('../data.json');
      var result = await response.json()
      var tempData = result.map( (item, index) => ({...item, id: index}))
      setLastIndex(tempData.length -1)
      setData(tempData)
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [])

    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
})
```

Comment: State setter being async is a class component problem, here lastIndex is a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) no matter how much time has passed it'll never change to the current value. The effect still has a missing dependency and lasIndex will never be anything but 0 so may as well set it to 0.

Comment: If you `lastIndex` as a dependency, it will cause an infinite re-render because we have `setLastIndex` inside that `useEffect`.
He is using `setLastIndex(lastIndex => lastIndex + 1);` (set new state based on previous state) will not cause the `stale closure`. You can get more information here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often

Comment: lastIndex is available to fetchData through closure but when component re renders it won't re run the effect so fetchData has a stale closure of lastIndex. That means that your solution is pointless to use lastIndex since it will only ever be `0`. You may as well do `result.map( (item,index) => ({...item,id:index})`. Pointless code in questions can only lead to pointless answers.

Comment: Agree, the lastIndex can be replace by `index` of each item.

stale closure of lastIndex: check my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will try this:

````
const SearchAppointments  = React.memo(() => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async() => {
    const response = await fetch('../data.json');
    const result = await response.json();

    setData(result.map( (item, index) => ({...item, id:index})))
  };

  useEffect( () => {
    fetchData();
  }, [])

    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
})```
````

Comment: Here, you are mapping the ```item.id``` to ```data```. However, what I actually wanted to map to ```data``` is the entire ```item``` (along with item.id)

Comment: I think you meant to do `result.map( (item,index) => ({...item,id:index})`

Comment: @HMR yes, my mistake)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need `lastIndex`?

There's `data.length`.
It can be used inside `setData(lastData=>...)`